# can't change current link color & background

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, target

I have created a simple example. I want to change the current color of a link. Here is the code:

```
<div id="link1">
    some content
</div>
<div id="link2">
    some content
</div>

 <div class="div1">             
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a data-tab="#link1" id="link-link1"href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a data-tab="#link2" id="link-link2"href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

CSS code to change current link color:

```
#link1:target ~ .div1 #navigation #link-link1,
#link2:target ~ .div1 #navigation #link-link2
{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This works but i need to define links before

```
<div id="link1">
    some content
</div>
<div id="link2">
    some content
</div>
```

And after it does not change the current color of the link, I tried `.div1 #navigation #link-link1 ~ #link1:target` and `.div1 #navigation #link-link1 #link1:target`.
It is still not working.

Comment: There isn't a previous sibling selector I'm afraid.

Comment: and exist any way how to do it? So i must define links on bottom site?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that links have very specific CSS codes (a:link a:visited: a:active a:hover) and you just change around the classes. If you want different styles for various links, try using this code

```
.class1 A:link {put styles here} 
.class1 A:visited {put styles here} 
.class1 A:active {put styles here}
.class1 A:hover {put styles here}

.class2 A:link {put styles here} 
.class2 A:visited {put styles here} 
.class2 A:active {put styles here} 
.class2 A:hover {put styles here}
```

And so on. For the html part, just use <div class="class1"><a href="blah">text</a></div>

Good luck :)

Comment: i know this, i tried it but it is not working for me. It change all links colors to defined in a:visited . hover and active work but i need to remain defined color when link is clicked.

Comment: On some platforms, these styles can be overwritten by a cpanel customization. I find that just adding html (<font color="soandso">) **after** a <a href=""> code is the quickest, albeit more tedious, way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the hex colors, They are not proper.

Change

```
#000
```

To

```
#000000
```

Always 6 numbers

Suggestion: Don't use css, you won't need it.

Instead use:

```
<div id="link2" style="color:#40B3DF;">
    <p> some content </p>
</div>
```

This gives blue text. Change the #40B3DF to #FFFFFF

Or if you need to use css:

```
{
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: okey but this is not my problem. color: #fff; is acteptadle and it is working too.